# Lock current document using lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a document and a copy of the document. I want to create a document lock for the document using LotusScript.

I have separately put the current document inside Computer view and copy document inside Draft view. Below here the action to create a copy.

**Create copy**

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ns As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim newdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection

    Set db= ns.CurrentDatabase
    Set dc= db.UnprocessedDocuments

    If dc.Count<>1 Then
        Messagebox "No or too many documents selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set doc= dc.GetFirstDocument
    Set newdoc= doc.CopyToDatabase(db)
    Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue("PStatus", "Draft")
    Call newdoc.Save(True, False)
End Sub
```

**Save Button**

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim view As NotesView

    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set view = db.GetView("Draft")
    Set doc = view.GetDocumentByKey("Draft", True)
    vpswd = Inputbox$("Pls input code to save :")

    If vpswd = "o" Then

        uidoc.EditMode = True
        Set doc = uidoc.Document
        Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
        If doc.PStatus(0) = "Draft" Then
            Set newdoc= doc.CopyToDatabase(db)
            Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue("PStatus", "Active")
            Call newdoc.Save(True, False)
        End If
        Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SaveOptions" , "1")

        Call uidoc.Save
        Call uidoc.Close
    End If


End Sub
```

How can I lock a current document every time I create a copy of the document? E.g current document will lock when the copy document created.

Another question is, for copy document, after I saved, I want to replace the current document as a copy document and a copy document will be a live document. While the current document will not be deleted from the database but deleted from Computer view and displayed in the "Archived" view.

And inside Draft view, copy document will be deleted from view. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking a document should be implicit. Make sure that you use the Status field in all documents. E.g. when you create the copy, set the status of the copied document to "Copied" and the nw documof nt to "Draft". You have to cover all different status changes. Best is also to add one field that contains a unique document Id that can never be changed. Maybe also add a version number.

Examples of statuses:

- Draft: document under construction (only one, cannot be copied)
- Current: valid document (only one, can be copied)
- Copied: Current document that has been copied (only one, cannot be copied)
- Archived: document that has been replaced (more than one, cannot be copied)

It might help to create a STD, a State Transition Diagram.

Comment: I will try to set the status as your suggestion. I'm still new with notes so I kinda slow with this but improving. May I ask, can you suggest any syntax or way on how can I replace a document with another document data when I click save. Any help I appreciated!

Comment: This has got little to do with Notes... You should study the statuses and the operations executed on the documents that might change a status. Operations can be illegal or admitted, depending on the status. Why do you want to replace a document? In what situation do you need to do that?

Comment: As I mention on my question, I want to save a draft document to be active, and current active document change to status inactive. So the draft document will replace the active document. That's why I want to replace the document. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Inactive, or Archived? All you have to do is to change the status of both documents, the one with status Draft to Active and the other one from Active to Archived. I suppose your real question here is: when I'm in the Draft document, how can I get the currently Active one? You will have to look for it, in a lookup view, using the same key as used for the Draft document. Searching a view is done with GetDocumentByKey. Build a view, preferably hidden and used only for looking up, with 2 columns: the field documentId and the field Status.

Comment: Sorry, I mean Archived. So to search using GetDocumentByKey, I have to change through save button? Because when I click save button, the document with Draft status will change to Active status and REPLACED current document which the current document with Active status, change to Archived status.

Comment: Yes, during the save you have to change the status of the Active document to Archived.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem, I cannot succeed with your suggestion. I cannot proceed to save the document and change the status. I add getDocument by key and also replaceItemValue, but it show error "variant does not contain object" when I click button. I also don't know how to set for "Active" document. I have update save button code, please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, draft document and current active document is in different view, how can I compare them by documentID? Sorry if I'm asking too many.

Comment: I suggested earlier to give a document a unique Id. I think much of the confusion comes from the word document, that means either a (physical) Notes document or your higher level (logical) document. You should find different words to represent these entities, like Story and Version. A Story is unique, it should have only one Story Id, yet there may be many versions of the same Story. Each Version has a status, and by def. there is only one Version with the status Draft, and only one is Active. If you give each Version its own Version number, it is possible to uniquely identify a Version too.

Comment: If your Save button is on the form, it can be much shorter. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will look forward from you. I will try to get it work later.

Comment: It gets too difficult to explain what your possibilities are. Maybe discuss this elsewhere? On Skype? You can send me a DM on Twitter, see my profile.

Comment: Okay sure, I will DM you on your twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar.  When a new version, as I call it, is created, it is the "draft" document.  The previous document is an "approved" document.  User get to see only the approved until the new version is approved, then the older approved document is archived out of the db.  If you want all versions to stay in the db, but only the newer document brought up, you could use what I call a HistoryID field.  Basically I have a field on every document that has up to three values in it:

TheUNID
ParentUNID:TheUNID:Parent
TheUNID:ChildUNID:Child

The "theUNID" field is computed when composed so it never changes.  If a new version or draft is created, the HistoryID would now have two values:

TheUNID
TheUNID:ChildUNID:Parent

This let's you know you now have a new draft and the document you are on is actually a parent.  The "ChildUNID" is actually "theUNID" of the draft document you just created.

On the child document or the new draft document you put in the HistoryID:

TheUNID
ParentUNID:TheUNID:Parent

This way your draft knows who it's parent is.

In your code in your db, you just have any document that gets opened check the HistoryID field first.  If there is a child, you take the user to the child.  It doesn't matter what parent gets opened or how far back the generations go, your code continues to iterate through the HistoryID until the current child document is found that doesn't have a parent.  Sound good?

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Can I know how many exactly field I need to insert inside form. And how can I implemented this inside lotusscript?

Comment: I use three fields.  UNID is the uniqueID of the document.  It changes based on the uniqueID and is a computed field.  I use a LookupID field that is the uniqueID at the time of creation, but never changes.  Then I use the HistoryID field as detailed before.  Here is a dump of code that may be helpful.  My instructions are in the instructions form of the db.  http://skylab.ironclads.com/upload.nsf/(DO)?OpenAgent&TEMP=SKYBBBKMQ9